# How to Include mage.php of Magento in cakephp

Tags: magento-1.7, cakephp-2.2, cakephp-2.3

I have install magneto 1.7 in cakephp 2x root directory and i want include Mage class in user controller.

My cakephp root directory stractucher is:-

```
skinrevive/app
skinrevive/magento
skinrevive/lib
skinrevive/plugins
skinrevive/vendors
```

I am trying below code but every time say Mage class not found.

```
App::build(array('Magento' => array($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/skinrevive/magento')));
App::uses('Mage', 'Magento/app');
```

OR

```
App::import('Magento','Mage',array('file' => 'app/Mage.php'));
```

Please help.